# Tutorial to create a protractor project in Netbeans IDE. (Installed Netbeans 7.4)

Tags: angularjs, ide, netbeans-7, protractor

I'm going to write hell lot of test cases using protractor framework. I've installed Netbeans IDE for that but I'm not able configure it correctly for my tests. It would be very helpful if  anybody can give a tutorial to create a protractor project in netbeans IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The future release of Netbeans 8.1 will have support for Protractor

[wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB81#Protractor](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB81#Protractor)

For now, you can download [Netbeans nightly](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB81#Protractor) which also has configuration for Protractor by going to the **Project Properties**, and clicking on the category, **Selenium Testing**

[image]

Comment: That's great, but as mentioned below, webstorm is more suitable

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use webstorm instead as it's more adapted to protractor. Even if you manage to install it you won't get any support as i don't think netbeans is used with protractor.

Comment: Yes that's right. I'm currently using Webstorm only but since it's not free and since I'm new to javascript world, wanted to know if we can use it for scripting purposes.